# React Native - Expo Error - "export 'auth' was not found in 'firebase' :

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

Building an auth app using native with the expo.

Create `firebase.js` file and link the app

exported `auth` properly in `firebase.js` still can't import `auth` in my `LoginScreen.js` file

It keeps throwing the error

```
"export 'auth' was not found in 'firebase'
  11 | 
  12 |     const handleSignup = () =>{
> 13 |         auth
     |        ^
  14 |         .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
password)
  15 |         .then(usersCredentials => {
  16 |             const user = userCredentials.user;
```

Firebase.js

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
// import * as firebase from "firebase";
import firebase from "firebase/app"
// import "firebase/auth"
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyB4R4he96dglIFlyGQyP8aYKLtzfGGc_ZQ",
  authDomain: "fir-auth-ec54a.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "fir-auth-ec54a",
  storageBucket: "fir-auth-ec54a.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "211989329100",
  appId: "1:211989329100:web:765e2715889a0fc374be69"
};

// Initialize Firebase
 let app;
 if (firebase.apps.length == 0) {
     app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
 } else{
     app = firebase.app()
 }

 const auth = firebase.auth()

 export default { auth }
```

dependencies in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
```

**EDIT**

This is where I am importing the firebase:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-web'
// import firebase from "firebase/app"
// import "firebase/auth"
import { auth } from '../firebase'

const LoginScreen = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const handleSignup = () =>{
    auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(userCredentials => {
        const user = userCredentials.user;
        console.log(user.email)
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error.message))
}

return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={styles.container}
        behavior='padding'
    >
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput 
                placeholder="Email"
                value={email}
                onChangeText={text => setEmail(text) }
                style={styles.input}
            />
            <TextInput 
                placeholder="Password"
                value={password}
                onChangeText={text => setPassword(text) }
                style={styles.input}
                secureTextEntry
            />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {}}
                style={styles.buttonText}
            >`enter code here`
            <Text style={styles.button}>Log In</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={handleSignup}
                style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}
            >
            <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText}>Register</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </ KeyboardAvoidingView>

)}

export default LoginScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
    },
    inputContainer:{
        width: '80%',
    
},
input:{
    backgroundColor:'white',
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 5,
},
buttonContainer:{
    width: '60%',
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    marginTop: 40,
},
button:{
    backgroundColor: '#1674B5',
    width:'100%',
    padding:15,
    borderRadius:10,
    alignItems:'center'
},
buttonText:{
    color:'white',
    fontWeight:'700',
    fontSize:16,
},
buttonOutline:{
    backgroundColor:'white',
    marginTop:5,
    borderColor:'#1674B5',
    borderWidth:2,
},
buttonOutlineText:{
    color:'#1674B5',
    fontWeight:'700',
    fontSize:16,
},})
```

But now I can't see anything on the Web Browser Emulator. VS code console is showing `"Build Complete"`. What should I do to fix it?

This is the Screenshot of my emulator now:

[image]

Snack is giving me this error

[image]

Comment: Can you share your complete file where auth is being imported?

Comment: @dhramaraj yes, I just edited the file where I am importing `auth`

Comment: Please include relevant logs in your question. A blank screenshot is not helpful as it could mean a multitude of different errors have occurred.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience.  I ran the app on Snack and this is the error I am getting on the console.  `undefined is not a function (near '..._firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged...')
(Device)`

Comment: I have added another error screenshot in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has recently undergone significant changes; make use of this.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  ....
};

// Use this to initialize the firebase App
const firebaseApp =firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Use these for auth

const auth = firebase.auth();

export {auth};
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is exporting an object, as the default export, with a single property of `auth`:

```
export default { auth }
```

To import this object, you would use:

```
import lib from './yourfile.js';

const auth = lib.auth;
// or
const { auth } = lib;
```

However, if you intend on using:

```
import { lib } from './yourfile.js';
```

Remove the `default` keyword to define an export called `auth` using either:

```
const auth = firebase.auth()
export { auth }
```

or

```
export const auth = firebase.auth();
```

Comment: I did `import firebase from "firebase/app"` and did `const auth = firebase.auth();

 export { auth };`  to export. Now the console is showing `Buiding complete`, but nothing is rendering on the web browser.

I'm using the web browser as the emulator.